# javascript and greasemonkey question

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey, getelementbyid

i wanna get a price inside a page and then multiple it by 0.93 then write the result after first price. but i couldn't be able to grab the price from page.

for example i want to grap "900 TL" string from "**900 TL**"

you can see all codes of page by visiting http://www.sahibinden.com/cok_temiz_asus_f3jp_t7200_2ghz_2gb_ram_256_mb_harici_ekran_ka-49WQQaXQQ17829315WQQpXQQdisplayitem

thx a lot.

edit: the "f16 bold" string counts only 1 on that page. so maybe we can get "900 TL" with this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('f16 bold')[0].textContent = document.getElementsByClassName('f16 bold')[0].textContent + ' (' + parseInt(document.getElementsByClassName('f16 bold')[0].textContent)*0.93 + ')';
```

Note: getElementsByClassName has poor browser support (in Firefox, 3.0+ I believe).